# What is the difference between inherited method (prototype) and static method (expression)?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have these two examples of functions on a string that do exactly the same:

```
//ex1 - inherited method
String.prototype.slugLower = function() {
    return this.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
}

"hello World".slugLower();


//ex2 - static method
String.slugLower = function(str) {
    return str.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
}

String.slugLower("hello World");
```

Both will return `"hello-world"`. What is the difference between them? I mean performance / best practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is a method attached to a prototype. The second is a method attached to the `String` object. In a classical OO language, they would be called "inherited method" and "static method", respectively.

The performance difference is minuscule, and really shouldn't matter here. What should is: if you think a method is a behaviour of every object in a class of objects, it should be a prototypal (inherited) method. If you think it should be a behaviour that is related to multiple objects of the class or the class itself, you should use the second pattern. For example, "pee on" or "bark this loudly" is a behaviour of each dog: `Dog.prototype.peeOn`, `Dog.prototype.barkWithVolume`; "how many dogs in the world?" or "make a new dog" is not a behaviour of each dog, but of "doghood" and a pair of dogs, respectively: `Dog.census` and `Dog.spawnPuppy`.

Comment: I like the comparison to `static` and `inherited` in class-based languages.  The analogy slightly breaks down because the `inherited` instance is shared by all object instances.  But still a good parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Method defined in prototype will be available in all Object. For the most of use cases, `'your object'.protoype` will be the best practice.

Another example :

```
var myObject = function monObject() {
   /*...*/ 

   this.function1 = function function1() {
      /*...*/ 
   };
};

myObject.prototype.function2 = function function2() {
  /*...*/ 
};
```

Then if you create 2 objects

```
var obj1 = new myObject();
var obj2 = new myObject();
```

Then you have this :

```
obj1.function1 !== obj2.function1
```

but :

```
obj1.function2 === obj2.function2
```

`function1()` is re create on every new `myObject`.
Is it clear ?

Comment: I hope you didn't mean literally `Object` when you wrote "For the most of use cases, `Object.protoype` will be the best practice." I don't want my dog peeing method to be on `Object`, should be on `Dog`.

Comment: Now (while accurate), this answer doesn't address the OP's `ex2` example.

Comment: @Amadan, yes I mean 'your object'.prototype !

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is define a function to do this

```
function slugLower(str){
     return str.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
}
```

Both your examples will change the String object, there is some side effects, the first example is `instance method`, the second one is `static function`

Comment: Why create an external function when it can only be applied to String object

Comment: You will change the String object, most case the String instances do not need this method, you faced they carry something they don't need

Comment: @SandrinaPereira: Consider if one day the ecmascript committee happens to introduce a new method on `String` that has the same name as your method but behaves completely differently (maybe needing an argument or produce different output). Before you say it's theoretical remember that it **has** happened before: to the prototype.js library. Prototype.js had the idea that they can improve javascript by extending the prototypes of native objects. Then es5 broke their library (which was very popular BTW, since it was included by default with Ruby on Rails)

Comment: Here's another example of the problem described by @slebetman https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2402

Comment: that's a good point. @Amadan what do you think about it? Should I only create a declaration function in this particular example? Because i don't have an object associated to it. slugLower() is being used in a lot of places on my code, it's like a "global function"

Comment: I agree with @slebetman: the discussion in my answer mostly concerns the distinction itself, completely overlooking that you're monkey-patching a core class. Monkey patching, while nice and useful, *can* be dangerous, precisely for the reasons slebetman quotes.

Comment: I understood. Thank you guys for the explanation